# Getting value from mysql result array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm having problem getting a value from array contains json.
Here is the JSON i'm getting (printed by `console.log(rows[0])` ) :

```
[ { User_ID: 28,
    Email: 'bla1111@s.com'} ]
```

But when trying to print the User_ID or Email:

```
console.log(rows[0].User_ID)
```

The output is `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON data already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's what you get after executing `console.log(rows[0])`, then you have another array to deal with. This should do the trick:

```
console.log(rows[0][0].User_ID); //28
```

Reason being, `rows[0]` returns an array, so once again you need to select the appropriate index from that returned value: `rows[0][0]`. This will give you the object you want.

Answer (score 1):

`rows[0]` looks like an array. Try,

```
console.log(rows[0][0].User_ID)
```